# django datepicker format change

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-forms

Im trying to change the datepicker format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd-mm-yyyy. So far I've added `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` in settings.py to `['%d-%m-%Y']`, but this didnt change anything. I also changing it via jquery based on proposed solution in this [site](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/jquery/1209/jqueryui-datepicker-tips-tricks) but it didnt help also.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
    });
</script>
```

Its quite a trivial problem but I cant seem to find a way how to solve it.

forms.py

```
class Calendar(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'


    class AdForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
        time_limit = forms.DateInput(format=['%d-%m-%Y'])
    
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['time_limit'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control mb-3 datepicker'})

    class Meta:
        model = Ad
        fields = ('time_limit')
        
        widgets = {
            'time_limit': Calendar(),
        }
```

The result is still as such:

[image]

Comment: Do you need to use localization in your app? I'm asking because the date format changes when USE_L10N = True

Comment: I dont need to localize but the results of the datepicker didnt change regardless of USE_L10N = True/ False

Comment: I don't sure but try this in settings.py :```DATE_FORMAT = 'j N, Y'```
```USE_L10N = False```

Comment: No effect either

Comment: I added in the answers a solution that should work, let me know if it works and if you need additional details

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` creating a `formats` folder under your main project dir and then adding a custon format file for each language you need as describer in [the official Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files).

You can see how to customize the `FORMAT_MODULE_PATH` and what is the full list of the (editable) available formats [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#format-module-path).

Sample folder structure to edit the english format:

```
mysite/
    formats/
        __init__.py
        en/
            __init__.py
            formats.py
```

And then the `formats.py`

```
DATE_FORMAT = 'j N, Y'
```

In the `settings.py` file

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
USE_L10N = True
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = [
    'my_app.formats',
]
```

Comment: Nothing changed. Does it change for you if you try?

Comment: Could you try changing the value of your USE_L10N? Using USE_L10N set to True, the locale format has higher precedence

Comment: I tried it before. Did not have any effect. Does it change the format for you?

Comment: Yes, it is working on my local with the following in the settings:

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
USE_L10N = True
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = [
    'my_app.formats',
]. I'm going to add it in the answer, it is not readable here. PS: can you post your settings?

Comment: Not sure how you managed it but the format is not changing for me. I also posted a ticket in the django forum and received an answer (https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/dateinput-format-not-changing-from-default/10009/7)  that you cannot change it within django, instead javascript shoud be used. Its due to HTML5

Comment: I'm just displaying the date in the template, without using the input form. You are correct, in fact the docs says "The displayed date format will differ from the actual value — the displayed date is formatted based on the locale of the user's browser, but the parsed value is always formatted yyyy-mm-dd.". I followed your link here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date